# Intermittent error 1310 with MSI installation

Tags: windows-installer

One of our MSI installers has an intermittent problem that I cannot fathom. I cannot even work out where I should look for more information.

Sometimes when installing (or repairing a previous install) the user receives a message "Error writing to file: [PATH]. Verify you have access to that directory." It is not always on the same file or files. At the point the dialog appears, the file in question does not exist. Frequently, hitting 'Retry' will let the installation continue. Sometimes you will have to retry a few times. Often there are multiple files with problems but rarely the same ones.

I have generated a log of a repair where this kind of problem occurred by running:

```
msiexec /fa "TracsExe-24.0.132.1.msi" /L*V "repair.log"
```

The log file is at http://justpaste.it/2tzg

In this case, the message appeared once for C:\tracsexe\productivity.exe, three times for C:\tracsexe\prtschedule.exe, once for C:\tracsexe\pstrim.bat, once for C:\tracsexe\svxroutes.exe and once for C:\tracsexe\validate.exe. The installation ultimately completed successfully with all files installed as they should be.

An excerpt from the log is as follows:

```
 Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=jsfvzzol.exe|svxroutes.exe,SourceCabKey=svxroutesexe,DestName=svxroutes.exe,Attributes=512,FileSize=241664,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=24.0.132.1,Language=2057,InstallMode=4194304,,,,,,,)
 File: C:\tracsexe\svxroutes.exe;   Overwrite;  Won't patch;    REINSTALLMODE specifies all files to be overwritten
 Source for file 'svxroutesexe' is compressed
 Re-applying security from existing file.
 Verifying accessibility of file: svxroutes.exe
 Note: 1: 2318 2:  
 Note: 1: 2318 2:  
 Note: 1: 1310 2: 0 3: C:\tracsexe\svxroutes.exe 
 Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
 Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1310 
 Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
 Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
 Product: TracsExe 24.0.132.1 -- Error 1310. Error writing to file: C:\tracsexe\svxroutes.exe.  System error 0.  Verify that you have access to that directory.
```

I have searched for error 1310 and it tells me that it is because I do not have the necessary permissions to access the file. However the command was run from an Administrator command line so I should have permissions, and anyway the file has just been deleted so I seem to have permissions, and hitting 'Retry' normally works so I did have permissions after all.

The installer was created with WiX, if that's relevant. Not sure what other information may be important.

What do you think we should do next to try and find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    Click Start, and then click Run.
    In the Open box, type msiexec /unreg, and then press ENTER.
    Click Start, and then click Run.
    In the Open box, type msiexec /regserver, and then press ENTER.
This is from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296175